# Avoiding the Grid of Doom™ in Git-Flow

Tags: git, gitflow

My project follows the [Git Flow branching model](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/). Development happens on `develop`, which is merged into `master` and tagged there for releases. Hotfixes happen in branches branched off the current `master`.

However, current development also needs the hotfixes, so each hotfix branch is merged into `develop` as well.

This creates very ugly revision graphs, especially develop/hotfixes are merged often in a short timeframe:

[image: Ugly revision graph]

Is this a problem people usually have with Git-Flow, and is there an easy fix for it?

Comment: How often are you releasing a new version and are you using hotfix branches only for fixes that can't wait till the next scheduled release?

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau can be multiple times a day, but usually every couple of days. Hotfix branches only for fixes that can't wait, yes.

Comment: Why are the aesthetics of a revision graph a problem?

Comment: Doesn't [rebase](https://www.atlassian.com/git/articles/git-team-workflows-merge-or-rebase/) kind of solve this problem?

Comment: @Cuthbert to an extent, but you can't rebase master back onto develop without force-pushing, which is no option.

Comment: As an aside, and an attempt at creating something that one can look at for the workflow, might you look at [Explain Git with D3](http://onlywei.github.io/explain-git-with-d3/#freeplay) and generate a sequence of commands in there that one could replay to point out where things got strange and how to handle this workflow better? For example, typing "git branch dev;
git checkout dev;
git commit;
git checkout master;
git commit;
git commit;
git commit" (well, not the ';') produces something that will generate the same for you and me that you can say "ah ha, do this instead".

Comment: What are all those `Merge branch 'develop'` commits though? The bottom merge is from one of the hotfix branches you mentioned, so what are the others?

Comment: @Useless those are merges of the develop branch into master

Comment: So it seems like the activity in that graph is mostly the very frequent merges from develop, and nothing to do with hotfix branches?

Comment: @Useless hotfix branches are the core issue. Since they're branched off of `master`, and have to be merged into `develop`, we're basically merging `master` back into `develop` causing the whole mess to happen.

Comment: Ah, so your problem is that you're merging every hot fix two or three times? (First to master, then to develop, lastly from develop to master again)?

Comment: @Useless yeah, that's it! Can't avoid that though, hotfixes have to be merged into `develop`.

Comment: @HannesStruß you say you’re releasing multiple times in a day? That probably means you’re in a web development scenario. I’ve found git-flow best suitable for “packaged” software, something to release for someone else to download, which can have multiple versions in the wild (its intermediate `release` branch get quite cumbersome for web development). Whenever I’m in web development, I’ve come to prefer a simpler flow with only `feature` branches on `master`, like for example the Github Flow https://guides.github.com/introduction/flow/

Comment: @HugoFerreira totally agree, the project I'm talking about is an Android app.

Answer (score 2):

> > so your problem is that you're merging every hot fix two or three times? (First to master, then to develop, lastly from develop to master again)?
>
> yeah, that's it! Can't avoid that though, hotfixes have to be merged into develop

Sure, but why merge from develop to master if nothing actually changed?

Take a look at one of those `master<-develop<-hotfix` merges: there should be no actual change in there (the hotfix was already merged directly to master, after all). If there's no change, just don't do it.

In any case, according to your linked doc, the only merges from develop to master should be going via a release branch. Instead you're keeping master in sync with your (unstable) development branch - don't.